# How to change background color of cell in table using java script

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change background color of single cell in table using java script.

During document i need style of all cell should be same ( so used style sheet to add this. ) , but on button click i need to change color of first cell.

following is the sample code

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" >        

    function btnClick()
    {
            var x = document.getElementById("mytable").cells;
            x[0].innerHTML = "i want to change my cell color";
            x[0].bgColor = "Yellow";            
    }
    </script>   
</head>
    <style>
    div
    {
    text-align: left; 
    text-indent: 0px; 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    td.td
    {
                 border-width : 1px; 
                 background-color: #99cc00;
                 text-align:center;

    }
    </style>  
  <body>
  <div>  
    <table id = "mytable" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
      <tr valign="top">
      <td class = "td"><br />  </td>
      <td class = "td"><br />  </td>
      </tr>
      <tr valign="top">
      <td class = "td"><br />  </td>
      <td class = "td"><br />  </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
      <input type="button" value="Click" OnClick = "btnClick()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this:

```
function btnClick() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mytable").getElementsByTagName("td");
    x[0].innerHTML = "i want to change my cell color";
    x[0].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";            
}
```

Set from JS, `backgroundColor` is the equivalent of `background-color` in your style-sheet.

Note also that the `.cells` collection belongs to a table *row*, not to the table itself. To get all the cells from all rows you can instead use `getElementsByTagName()`.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ekituv/edit#preview

Answer (score 10):

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding= "20">
    <tr>
    <td id="id1" ></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    document.getElementById('id1').style.backgroundColor='#003F87';
</script>
```

Put id for cell and then change background of the cell.

Answer (score 5):

```
document.getElementById('id1').bgColor = '#00FF00';
```

seems to work. I don't think `.style.backgroundColor` does.