# How to change the background of a row of table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, getelementbyid

In the javascript code, I add rows dynamically to a table. For each call, another single row is added. Based on the length of the table how would I implement the .insideHTML to a cell color.
Table is defined in the HTML as

```
    <table id="myTableData"  border="1" cellpadding="2" width = "100%">
    <tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Word</th>
            <th>Meaning</th>
            <th>Date Added (dd/mm/yyyy)</th>
     </tr>

     </table>
```

The javascript(.js) has the code to add a single row by:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= "Hello";
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML="World";
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML=".";
```

My first attempt was to call the whole row by:

`row.style.backgroundColor = '0000FF';`

Another attempt was to use this outside of the .js file

```
var tableElements = document.getElementById("myTableData");
for(var j = 0; j < tableElements.length; j++)
{
    var tableCells = tableElements[j] ;

    var rows = tableCells.getElementsByTagName("tr") ;

    rows.style.backgroundColor = "red";

}
```

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript to set the background color? Why don't you just use some css to target the table row?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change background color of cell in table using java script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517150/how-to-change-background-color-of-cell-in-table-using-java-script)

Comment: Your `tr` background is being overriden by `td` backbround

Comment: Are you wanting to use different colors for different rows, based on how many there are (based on this line in your question: `"Based on the length of the table how would I implement the .insideHTML to a cell color."`)?  Or (based on your code logic) are you just trying to make all of the table rows one color?

Comment: What does tr and td backround? How would I overside the TR background? @vmatm

Comment: You were right about the duplicate expect mine was row not cell. VMAtm

Answer (score 2):

Well your second attempt fails because of this:

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName)

> The Element.getElementsByTagName() method returns a live
>   HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.

So setting a collection to a style does not work, you would need to loop it and set it to the individual elements in the collection.

```
var rows = tableCells.getElementsByTagName("tr") ;
for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

---

But if setting it directly when you create the row is a bug, you have a css problem. A better solution is to use classes

CSS:

```
row.error td { background-color: red; }
```

So now set the class in your JavaScript

```
row.classList.add("error");
```

or

```
row.className = "error";
```

Comment: Both of the ways to change the background color doesn't work. I should mention that each row is added by a function call from a button. So the javascript woult have to change the row collor after the data entered by `row.insertCell(2).innerHTML="World";`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the answer provided by epascarello and it didn't work for me.
I've tried this and it worked:

```
for (var i=0; i<rows.cells.length; i++) {
    rows.cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: Interesting. @epascarello would you like to comment?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var tableElements = document.getElementById("myTableData");
for(var j = 0; j < tableElements.rows.length; j++){
    var row = tableElements.rows.item(j);
    row.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
</script>
```

Examples above did not work for me. I used this snipped at the bottom of the html file.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let bodyTab = document.querySelector('.tab').tBodies[0];
let trCount = bodyTab.rows.length;
for (let i = 1; i < trCount; i = i + 2)
{
    bodyTab.rows[i].style.backgroundColor = '#cccfff';
}
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation to the code.