# Change the colour of a cell in a table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have created a 10x10 table using JavaScript and it's displayed in a html page,

How can I get it so that when the word for the corresponding cell pops up in a console it changes the color of that cell?

Comment: Check out the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517150/how-to-change-background-color-of-cell-in-table-using-java-script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function btnClick() {
var x = document.getElementById("mytable").getElementsByTagName("td");
x[0].innerHTML = "i want to change my cell color";
x[0].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Did you meant this...

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[9].getElementsByTagName('td')[4];
elem.style.backgroundColor = "#fca";
```

```css
tr td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px solid black">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>sfsf</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```