# How to change background color only if background is not set in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

The table below has some types of classes. 
I would like to change color cell `1` and `2` by clicking,it means the color is changed only if no background-color is set in each cells.

Are there any method for this? Thanks

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
  });
});
```

```css
#aqua {
    border-bottom: 3px solid aqua;
}
#green {
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<td id="1">1</td>
<td id="aqua">2</td>
<td id="green">3</td>
</table>
```

Comment: This might be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517150/how-to-change-background-color-of-cell-in-table-using-java-script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add class which will give it `background:yellow` style. this way whenever any other color given to it by id, the id selector style will get the priority although the class;

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('default-yellow');
  });
});
```

```css
#aqua {
    border-bottom: 3px solid aqua;
}
#green {
    background-color:green;
}
.default-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<td id="1">1</td>
<td id="aqua">2</td>
<td id="green">3</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the click event handler, first check if the element has any colour set on it and change the colour only if it doesn't meet your required criteria. You can use `$(this).css('background-color')` to get the current colour.

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    if ($(this).css('background-color') === 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#aqua {
  border-bottom: 3px solid aqua;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="aqua">2</td>
  <td id="green">3</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() { 
    $(this).addClass('test');
  });
});
```

```css
#aqua {
    border-bottom: 3px solid aqua;
}
#green {
    background-color:green;
}
.test{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<td id="1">1</td>
<td id="aqua">2</td>
<td id="green">3</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the element has a transparent background-color

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') {
      $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
    };
  });
});
```

```css
#aqua {
    border-bottom: 3px solid aqua;
}
#green {
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<td id="1">1</td>
<td id="aqua">2</td>
<td id="green">3</td>
</table>
```